# Add shortcut to desktop option in wpf setup wizard

Tags: c#, wpf, setup-wizard

I know how to make shortcut on desktop etc..

But is there a option to use Checkbox and set up some logic for it like?  :

```
if(CHECKBOXA1 = isSelected)
 {
    create desktop shortcut
 }
else
{}
```

Also how do I set up control of the checkboxes, radiobuttons etc?

Comment: Which setup wizard are you using? Clickonce, wix, etc?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I am using regular one downloaded by visual studio. No idea if it has any name. Is there some 'better' one?

Comment: It depends on your requirements, like do you need bootstrap .NET, etc, but WiX/MSI and clickonce are more flexible for that. You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401195/how-to-create-a-custom-wpf-setup-wizard

Comment: Like I think that original .msi installer of Visual Studio should be fine. But only one thing I don't know how to do, and that is how do I set conditions. Radiobuttons and Checkboxes have description : 'Provides a set of Radiobuttons/Checkboxes, that can be customized to control the installation.' But if I check the properities of specific item it has only BannerText, BodyText, checkbox1Label/Property/Value/Visible. So I don't really know if it is even possible. I hope so. It is simple program, so I think that some 'fancy' installer is not much needed.