# Wpf .net core application installer with custom forms

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, .net-core, installation

I already saw other questions about windows intallers for .net. for Wrapping up:

I have a .net core 3 wpf application and i want to make a setup for my users to install the app:

**1- What is the simple way to create an installer for application?**

**2- I need to have some forms in setup wizard - for example i need to get a url from user before install**

So, how can i achieve these functions and package my software?

Comment: You can crate a WPF setup project to design the  wizard UI,then you call the Windows Installer service to install your application.There are a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401195/how-to-create-a-custom-wpf-setup-wizard) of making a setup wizard.